# Set Neotree width by percentage?

Tags: window, neotree

I currently have this in my config file for [neotree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree):

```
;(neotree-show)
  (setq neo-window-width 25)
```

Does anyone know how I can set the window width to 25 percent?

Comment: You'd have to calculate this using a variety of the window/frame geometry components.  It's not built-in to neotree, but is doable.